# Calculating a rolling count over a specified window

Tags: sql, sql-server

The sample data may help explain what I'm trying to do more than explaining it, so I'll begin with that.

Here's the data I'm currently working with:

```
+-------------------------+--------------+
|        CallStart        | CallDuration |
+-------------------------+--------------+
| 2017-09-15 09:15:15.313 | 00:01:28     |
| 2017-09-15 09:15:15.317 | 00:01:45     |
| 2017-09-15 09:16:45.603 | 00:01:31     |
| 2017-09-15 09:17:00.637 | 00:01:24     |
| 2017-09-15 09:18:20.853 | 00:01:42     |
| 2017-09-15 09:18:25.870 | 00:01:24     |
| 2017-09-15 11:27:05.117 | 00:00:59     |
| 2017-09-15 11:31:16.053 | 00:01:18     |
| 2017-09-15 11:34:41.627 | 00:01:00     |
| 2017-09-15 12:16:45.413 | 00:01:01     |
| 2017-09-15 12:18:15.820 | 00:01:05     |
| 2017-09-15 12:30:43.607 | 00:01:04     |
| 2017-09-15 12:31:48.817 | 00:00:55     |
| 2017-09-15 12:35:14.563 | 00:00:59     |
| 2017-09-15 12:42:10.947 | 00:00:43     |
| 2017-09-15 12:56:28.807 | 00:01:14     |
| 2017-09-15 13:05:10.643 | 00:00:37     |
| 2017-09-15 13:20:08.400 | 00:00:37     |
| 2017-09-15 14:30:12.607 | 00:00:59     |
| 2017-09-15 14:31:22.807 | 00:00:49     |
| 2017-09-15 15:19:47.240 | 00:01:07     |
| 2017-09-15 16:04:47.753 | 00:00:55     |
| 2017-09-15 16:58:08.080 | 00:00:55     |
| 2017-09-15 17:05:04.557 | 00:00:50     |
| 2017-09-15 17:20:42.753 | 00:00:58     |
| 2017-09-15 17:28:09.140 | 00:01:05     |
| 2017-09-15 17:39:46.690 | 00:00:38     |
| 2017-09-15 17:40:21.957 | 00:01:05     |
| 2017-09-15 17:43:47.570 | 00:01:08     |
| 2017-09-15 17:47:23.390 | 00:01:05     |
| 2017-09-15 17:47:28.410 | 00:00:56     |
| 2017-09-15 17:51:59.380 | 00:01:04     |
+-------------------------+--------------+
```

I am trying to get a rolling `COUNT(*)` for the number of occurrences in this data over a 15-minute timeframe.  The expected result for this data would be the following:

```
+-------------------------+--------------+------------------+
|        CallStart        | CallDuration | DropsIn15Minutes |
+-------------------------+--------------+------------------+
| 2017-09-15 09:15:15.313 | 00:01:28     |                1 |
| 2017-09-15 09:15:15.317 | 00:01:45     |                2 |
| 2017-09-15 09:16:45.603 | 00:01:31     |                3 |
| 2017-09-15 09:17:00.637 | 00:01:24     |                4 |
| 2017-09-15 09:18:20.853 | 00:01:42     |                5 |
| 2017-09-15 09:18:25.870 | 00:01:24     |                6 |
| 2017-09-15 11:27:05.117 | 00:00:59     |                1 |
| 2017-09-15 11:31:16.053 | 00:01:18     |                2 |
| 2017-09-15 11:34:41.627 | 00:01:00     |                3 |
| 2017-09-15 12:16:45.413 | 00:01:01     |                1 |
| 2017-09-15 12:18:15.820 | 00:01:05     |                2 |
| 2017-09-15 12:30:43.607 | 00:01:04     |                3 |
| 2017-09-15 12:31:48.817 | 00:00:55     |                3 |
| 2017-09-15 12:35:14.563 | 00:00:59     |                3 |
| 2017-09-15 12:42:10.947 | 00:00:43     |                4 |
| 2017-09-15 12:56:28.807 | 00:01:14     |                2 |
| 2017-09-15 13:05:10.643 | 00:00:37     |                2 |
| 2017-09-15 13:20:08.400 | 00:00:37     |                2 |
| 2017-09-15 14:30:12.607 | 00:00:59     |                1 |
| 2017-09-15 14:31:22.807 | 00:00:49     |                2 |
| 2017-09-15 15:19:47.240 | 00:01:07     |                1 |
| 2017-09-15 16:04:47.753 | 00:00:55     |                1 |
| 2017-09-15 16:58:08.080 | 00:00:55     |                1 |
| 2017-09-15 17:05:04.557 | 00:00:50     |                2 |
| 2017-09-15 17:20:42.753 | 00:00:58     |                1 |
| 2017-09-15 17:28:09.140 | 00:01:05     |                2 |
| 2017-09-15 17:39:46.690 | 00:00:38     |                2 |
| 2017-09-15 17:40:21.957 | 00:01:05     |                3 |
| 2017-09-15 17:43:47.570 | 00:01:08     |                3 |
| 2017-09-15 17:47:23.390 | 00:01:05     |                4 |
| 2017-09-15 17:47:28.410 | 00:00:56     |                5 |
| 2017-09-15 17:51:59.380 | 00:01:04     |                6 |
+-------------------------+--------------+------------------+
```

Sample data:

```
Create Table #Calls 
(
    CallStart DateTime,
    CallDuration Time(0)
);
Insert Into #Calls
Values (N'2017-09-15T09:15:15.313', N'00:01:28'),
    (N'2017-09-15T09:15:15.317', N'00:01:45'),
    (N'2017-09-15T09:16:45.603', N'00:01:31'),
    (N'2017-09-15T09:17:00.637', N'00:01:24'),
    (N'2017-09-15T09:18:20.853', N'00:01:42'),
    (N'2017-09-15T09:18:25.87', N'00:01:24'),
    (N'2017-09-15T11:27:05.117', N'00:00:59'),
    (N'2017-09-15T11:31:16.053', N'00:01:18'),
    (N'2017-09-15T11:34:41.627', N'00:01:00'),
    (N'2017-09-15T12:16:45.413', N'00:01:01'),
    (N'2017-09-15T12:18:15.82', N'00:01:05'),
    (N'2017-09-15T12:30:43.607', N'00:01:04'),
    (N'2017-09-15T12:31:48.817', N'00:00:55'),
    (N'2017-09-15T12:35:14.563', N'00:00:59'),
    (N'2017-09-15T12:42:10.947', N'00:00:43'),
    (N'2017-09-15T12:56:28.807', N'00:01:14'),
    (N'2017-09-15T13:05:10.643', N'00:00:37'),
    (N'2017-09-15T13:20:08.4', N'00:00:37'),
    (N'2017-09-15T14:30:12.607', N'00:00:59'),
    (N'2017-09-15T14:31:22.807', N'00:00:49'),
    (N'2017-09-15T15:19:47.24', N'00:01:07'),
    (N'2017-09-15T16:04:47.753', N'00:00:55'),
    (N'2017-09-15T16:58:08.08', N'00:00:55'),
    (N'2017-09-15T17:05:04.557', N'00:00:50'),
    (N'2017-09-15T17:20:42.753', N'00:00:58'),
    (N'2017-09-15T17:28:09.14', N'00:01:05'),
    (N'2017-09-15T17:39:46.69', N'00:00:38'),
    (N'2017-09-15T17:40:21.957', N'00:01:05'),
    (N'2017-09-15T17:43:47.57', N'00:01:08'),
    (N'2017-09-15T17:47:23.39', N'00:01:05'),
    (N'2017-09-15T17:47:28.41', N'00:00:56'),
    (N'2017-09-15T17:51:59.38', N'00:01:04');
```

I can *somewhat* get this to work via the following:

```
Select  CallStart,
        CallDuration,
        DropsIn15Minutes = 
        (
            Select  Count(*) 
            From    #Calls C2 
            Where   C2.CallStart Between DateAdd(Minute, -15, C1.CallStart) 
                                 And     C1.CallStart
        )
From    #Calls  C1
```

But, I would like to avoid the sub-query, in favor of a `COUNT(*) OVER ()` (or any other solution if possible) solution.

Is this possible to do?  Or is the sub-query the right solution for this?

Comment: why do some consecutive rows have the same number? do you need a total count in each group or sequential numbers?

Comment: @VamsiPrabhala Some consecutive rows have the same number because enough time had passed between them that one had fallen out of the 15-minute window.  This is only looking at counts for records, without groupings.

Comment: Is millisecond precision really important or can we truncate milliseconds to seconds?

Comment: @MartinSmith The precision isn't important, it can be truncated to seconds.

Comment: @MartinSmith Ah, I see where you're going with this - yes, that can work, actually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way - which may perform better than a nested loops join on a range if the table is big - would be to first create a numbers table...

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Numbers
(
N INT PRIMARY KEY
);

    WITH E1(N) AS 
    (
        SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
        SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
        SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
    )                                       -- 1*10^1 or 10 rows
    , E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b)   -- 1*10^2 or 100 rows
    , E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b)   -- 1*10^4 or 10,000 rows
    , E8(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E4 a, E4 b)   -- 1*10^8 or 100,000,000 rows
INSERT INTO dbo.Numbers
    SELECT TOP (60*60*24) -1 + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS N FROM E8;
```

And then use something along the following lines.

```
WITH Calls
     AS (SELECT *,
                --pre-truncate all call starts to second precision
                CallStart_sec = DATEADD(SECOND, DATEDIFF(SECOND, '20000101', CallStart), '20000101')
         FROM   #Calls),
     PreAgg
     AS (SELECT CallStart_sec,
                COUNT(*) AS Cnt
         FROM   Calls
         GROUP  BY CallStart_sec),
     Dates(D)
     --Todo - something else other than hardcoding the dates
     AS (SELECT CAST('2017-09-15' AS DATETIME2)),
     RT
     AS (SELECT *,
                Cume = SUM(Cnt) OVER (ORDER BY DATEADD(SECOND, N.N, Dates.D) 
                               ROWS BETWEEN 900 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
         FROM   Dates
                INNER JOIN dbo.Numbers N
                  ON N.N BETWEEN 0 AND 86399
                LEFT JOIN PreAgg P
                  ON P.CallStart_sec = DATEADD(SECOND, N.N, Dates.D))
SELECT C.CallStart_sec AS CallStart,
       CallDuration,
       DropsIn15Minutes = Cume
FROM   Calls C
       JOIN RT
         ON RT.CallStart_sec = C.CallStart_sec
```

Comment: Ah, I should have refreshed the page before posting.  I'll delete my answer, as it's essentially the same as yours following your advice.  This works very well, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Two other options:

using `cross apply()`:

```
select  
    CallStart
  , CallDuration
  , DropsIn15Minutes
from calls c
  outer apply (
    select DropsIn15Minutes = count(*)
    from calls i
    where i.callstart >= dateadd(minute,-15,c.CallStart)
      and i.callstart <= c.CallStart
    ) x
order by c.CallStart
```

---

using an `inner join`:

```
select  
    c.CallStart
  , c.CallDuration
  , DropsIn15Minutes = count(i.CallStart)
from calls c
  inner join calls i
    on i.callstart >= dateadd(minute,-15,c.CallStart)
   and i.callstart <= c.CallStart
group by c.CallStart, c.CallDuration
order by c.CallStart
```

---

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/PFCE43712

compare execution plans for all 3 (including yours): [dbfiddle.uk demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=2c063581f0e3a4ed13c7b7c673a6a658)

Comment: These do work, though these appear to take about twice as long to run :(.  I'm more wondering if there's a way to do this without hitting the table twice.

Comment: @Siyual - these hit it 33 times with your sample data. not twice - as it hits it once to get the outer rows and then once again for each outer row. So you would definitely want an index to support the seeks. Still could well be faster than mine though depending on the density of the data. If you have many rows per second I would expect the one in my answer to be more competitive.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select  CallStart,
        CallDuration,
COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY trunc(CallStart,'mi') - 
         numtodsinterval(mod(to_char(CallStart,'mi'),15),'minute'))
as DropsIn15Minutes 
From    #Calls  C1
```

Lets try this out and see how it works.

Ted

Comment: I don't know what syntax this is, but it's not SQL Server.

Comment: Ooops, sorry! Yes this is Oracle