# SQL Server: Getting all rows 10 minutes from each other

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

Hi I have a SQL problem i cannot solve. I am not sure whether this is a problem that can be solved in regular set-based operations.

Here it goes:

I have a table where every row is view of a document. I need to find the rows where the date between rows is fx 10 minutes of each other. Imagine a person accessing a document 13 times within 10 minutes (10 times within 10 seconds), i need to find these rows and the person doing this.

I other words catch the person accessing more than X documents in Y (Min/Sec), show me the document the person accessed.

It would be best to not have data aggregated, but just have one which counts the like ROW_NUMBER() OVER or Count(*) OVER.

Here is an example:

[image: Table]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46331544/73226

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way in SQL Server is probably to use `lead()` with an appropriate argument:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lead(happened, 12) over (partition by userkey, document order b happened) as next_happened_12
      from t
     ) t
where next_happened_12 < dateadd(minute, 10, happened);
```

The argument is  - 1.

This does not get all rows within 10 minutes of each other.  That would require a self-join and could be quite expensive.  `lead()` should be much more efficient and can take advantage of an index on `(userkey, document, happened)`.

Comment: Hi Gordon. Thanks!. 

But this does not help me i need all the rows. If it requires a self join, so be it. 
An user kan acces multiple documents within 10 minutes, the above partiton does not support that. Could i remove the "document" column from the partition and get the desired result?